# Could not initialize class sun.util.calendar.ZoneInfoFile intellij

Tags: java, intellij-idea, sdk, calendar

As the title says, I get this error while building my code but I'm not using the calendar.
[image: my java version]

I'm using this version of java and I'm using SDK 17.0 in IntelliJ, is there any reason this might be? every single one of my files is corrupt now, so no reason to post all of my code here.

Comment: Could you provide the IDE logs? `Help | Collect Logs and Diagnostic Data` The files can be uploaded at https://uploads.jetbrains.com (do not forget to specify the uploadID)

Comment: Upload id: 2021_12_07_FD3oWXfjYzkNwwpc (file: idea-logs-20211207-122517.zip)

Comment: Please share some screenshots, give some insights, a bit of context into your code maybe, whether you can reproduce it in a new project or not and similar. Right now the question - as it is - is impossible to work on (in particular for people outside of the Intellij Support who can not view the zip you uploaded). Voting to close as its broad and missing information.

Comment: @EgorKlepikov Please have a look at the answer posted below, the issue was found - you can probably speed up the support case now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue was found. It was caused by a misalignment of the language level:

[image]

After aligning both to **17**, it worked again.